# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: boot, partitioning, software-installation, 22.04, usb-drive

I was trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my 128 GB pendrive using another bootable pendrive mounted with the LTS version. I've tried it 5 times today. Each time during partition I choose 100MB for EFI partition and the rest for the `/` and click on Install. At the stage of copying files it shows this error:

[image]

Comment: A workaround is described at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Please read the whole thread before starting to use it. - Install a compressed image of Ubuntu Server 22.04 'Jammy' and after that install the desktop environment that you want. Installing the meta package `ubuntu-desktop` brings standard Ubuntu Desktop. You may prefer a lighter flavour and use `lubuntu-desktop` or `xubuntu-desktop` to get Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Bro I'm new to Linux, is there any other way to fix this?, is this error related to my pendrive. But when I plug the USB on windows it shows no problem I can add folder and format the drive , no signs of read only error. But when trying to install Ubuntu the described  error shows up

Comment: Bro, you got advice from the expert that I would ask, and I've been here 15 years. @sudodus has spent more time experimenting in this area than anybody else I know, and knows all the bugs and pain points. If there were an easier way to do your complex task, that person would be the first to know.

Comment: @Abhinav, There can be several different reasons why you have this problem. I suggested a method that is rather straightforward and can work around several obstacles. But if the problem is that your 128 GB pendrive is not really that big, only 'pretends' to be that big (a fake size), it might actually be impossible to install Ubuntu onto it. - Anyway, answering your question, yes there are other ways to install Ubuntu onto a USB drive, for example according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step).

Comment: the f3 package (fight fake flash) has programs to test your 128GB USB.  Launchpad bug 1396379 applies to 22.04, (Grub installs to wrong device, in your case, maybe the read only install media). Ubuntu 23.04 is not long term support, but does have a new installer that puts the bootoaders where you specify (check that the default is not your install media, if so, change it).